# in swift5 : popup on iPad is in right size, but on iPhone it is using the full screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift5

I want to display a popup with a TextView, on the iPad it works for a long time, but on the iPhone the popup gets 'fullscreen' - which I don't need and don't want.
How do I tell the iPhone that (like the iPad) it can only have an area of 300 x 300?
I've found several examples that all work fine on the iPad, but they all do this nonsense.
what am I doing wrong? (on real devices: iPhoneX, iPad2)

class NewPopupVCTextView: UIViewController,
UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoTextTextView: UITextView!

override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
          if infoTextTextView != nil,
            let presentingVC = presentingViewController {
            setTextViewContent()
            return infoTextTextView.contentSize
          }
          return super.preferredContentSize
    }
    set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
}

func setTextViewContent() {
    infoTextTextView.text = sourceText
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your source ViewController

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  popOver
//
//  Created by Lieng Hongky on 8/26/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Hongky. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func openPopover(_ sender: Any) {
        //MARK:====> instantiate the ViewController you want to be pop up
        let popVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "popVC")
        popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        
        //MARK:====> set the source view for the pop up VC
        popVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: self.view.center, size: CGSize.zero)
        
        //MARK:====>if you want to omit the arrow add this line of code
        popVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
        popVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        
        self.present(popVC, animated: true) {
            
        }
    }
    
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer - but with your suggestion I got the same result on the iPhone as before (my old version works exactly the same on the iPad) - so overall nothing has changed
Nevertheless many thanks

Comment: Can I see your implementation?
anyway here is my example working fine. you can clone the project and try.
https://github.com/lienghongky/ios_popover.git

Comment: first thanks for replying again. Sure, but it's not a small program, it's a pretty big app. what should i show? Which functions or calls (or classes, ...) should I show?

Comment: I tried your link (github.com/lienghongky/ios_popover.git) - is it an empty project ?! that was a bad joke - wasn't it?

Comment: No it isn’t joke! it isn’t empty